# Best Practice for moving a site using Assets

Tags: assets

I have a fairly big site with substantial use of Assets2 in development and am wondering what general guidelines / best practices anyone can suggest for when moving this to the production server? Any gotchas or preparation?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to update the server & domain paths for each file upload preference. And make sure the permissions are correct on the production server. Once you've moved everything over, update the indexes just to be sure and it should just work.

I've done this several times in the last few months and had very few problems. Assets 2 is superb.

Somewhat related, you can make a number of improvements to the config file that will make the migration more painless. Here's a good primer:

http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-server-setup-for-ee-2/

But you still need to manually update those file upload preferences.